# Delete mysqli php prepared statement sql

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, multiple-tables

I'm trying to find a solution for deleting multiple rows using a PHP mysqli prepared statement. At the moment my code deletes the records from one table. What would be the structure to delete rows from multiple tables?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
    `$sql ='DELETE FROM itm_pic_detail WHERE itm_pic_detail.id = ?';`
```

How would I write the following syntax:

`DELETE FROM itm_pic_detail, itm_details, itm_ref, itm_value WHERE itm_pic_detail.id = ?, itm_details.id =?, item_ref.desc_id = ?, itm_ref.id = ?`

Comment: use `AND` instead of commas, and add the table join info to the `USING` or `WHERE` condition. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html

Answer (score 1):

Below is the query I used somewhere... Please try it after changing fields as per your requirement...

**Example 1**

`DELETE user,items,orders FROM user LEFT JOIN items ON user.us_id = items.us_id LEFT JOIN orders ON items.od_id = orders.od_id WHERE user.us_id = $usrID`

**Example 2**

Below is what I wanted to do...

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE data_id='111';
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE data_id='111';
DELETE FROM table3 WHERE data_id='111';
```

For this I used below code

```
DELETE FROM table1, table2, table3 
USING table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 USING(data_id) 
    INNER JOIN table3 USING(data_id) 
WHERE table1.data_id = 111
```

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Thanks I will try your method looks exactly like the type of script I need. I should be able to replace the result with question marks and run a prepared statement using this syntax, right?

Comment: Is there any **practical** reasons in joining instead of separated queries? Join is an expensive operation which consumes resources

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the structure to delete rows from multiple tables?

If tables have no relations - you just perform several `DELETE` queries. There is nothing wrong to perform 2 queries to delete rows from 2 different tables

Comment: They all share the same ID so in that way they are linked. They are not indexed or foreign keys. I just wanted to use the most dynamic script. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @paynod: sharing the same `ID` has nothing to do with relations. I have a single sequence generator for all my 500 tables. So what? They still have nothing in common